# Select a property value from dbpedia resource with SPARQL

Tags: rdf, sparql, semantic-web, dbpedia

i'm trying to use SPARQL query on DBpedia.
I can retrieve all information about a resource with this query:

```
PREFIX db: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/
PREFIX prop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX onto: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
SELECT ?property ?value 
WHERE { db:Luciano_Ligabue ?property ?value  };
```

Now I want to retrieve the value of just one property such as dbpedia-owl: birthDate.
I'm trying in different way, but i can't retrieve the information needed.

Can someone help me, please?
Thank you guys.

Answer (score 2):

You need to show us the exact query you're using.  The one you've provided isn't legal SPARQL. The [sparql.org validator](http://sparql.org/query-validator.html) points out that there should be a `>` at the end of `PREFIX db: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/`, and that there should be no `;` at the final line.  So your query doesn't appear to return what you want it to;  it's not even a legal query.

DBpedia is sometimes a bit slow to respond, so I can't test this right now, but it sounds like you just need (I'm using the same prefixes that the [DBpedia endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql) uses, because it makes copying and pasting easier, but you've defined `db:` instead of `dbpedia:` and `onto:` instead of `dbpedia-owl:`):

```
select ?value where {
  dbpedia:Luciano_Ligabue dbpedia-owl:birthDate ?value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this you are looking for ?

```
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX prop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX onto: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
SELECT ?dob ?name ?homepage
WHERE{
dbo:Luciano_Ligabue onto:birthDate  ?dob.
dbo:Luciano_Ligabue prop:name ?name.
dbo:Luciano_Ligabue foaf:homepage ?homepage.
}
```