# Sparql query dbpedia istance's property and values in a domain

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I want to write a SPARQL query to retrieve all properties and values for an instance in a particular domain.  For example, I want all properties and values of the singer "Sting" only in "MusicalArtist" domain.  How can I do this?

Comment: This is not a forum;  it's a question and answer site for specific programming problems.  This is a pretty basic question, too, and one that's probably answered in the SPARQL specification.  That said, did you see this question, [Select a property value from dbpedia resource with SPARQL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22667987/1281433), whose author begins with "I can retrieve all information about a resource with this query: …"?

Comment: What do you mean that you 'want all properties and values of the singer "Sting" only in "MusicalArtist" domain'?  I understand what it would be get all the properties/values for a resource (e.g., the singer Sting), but I don't know what you mean by "properties and values … only in [some particular] domain".

Comment: @Joshua Taylor Thank you for your answer and  i'm sorry for the mistake about "forum". 
The question that you have indicated is a mine question. (Select a property value from dbpedia resource with SPARQL)
So the problem is: if use the Sparql query in the other post (that you have indicated)

    PREFIX db: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
    PREFIX prop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
    PREFIX onto: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> 
    SELECT ?property ?value
    WHERE { db:Barry_White ?property ?value  };

Comment: i have all properties and values about Barry_White.
Now in DBpedia we have a hierachy of class: for example Work, with children MusicalWork, Album, Single.

Now i want to retrieve the same informations of the specified query, but not in all DBpedia knowledge base. I want to know all properties of MusicalWork, and then the value for this properties for the instance "Barry White".

Comment: Do you mean that you the values (of properties of Barry_White) that are instances of the class MusicalWork?

Comment: exactly. I need to write two query. One for retrieve all about MusicalWork and the second for the values (of properties of Barry_White) that are instances of the class MusicalWork.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this is a pretty basic SPARQL question, and you'd be better off starting with a good tutorial on SPARQL, or sitting down with the [SPARQL 1.1 Query Language](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/) document.  Just skim through it, you don't need to memorize everything right away, but just get familiar with it.  After all, Stack Overflow isn't for reproducing standard documentation;  you're expected to already be familiar with that.

As you've shown in a previous question, you can ask for all properties of a given subject with a query like:

```
select ?p ?o where {
  dbpedia:Barry_White ?p ?o
}
```

You can select all instances of a particular class, e.g., dbpedia-owl:MusicalWork with a query like

```
select ?o where {
  ?o a dbpedia-owl:MusicalWork
}
```

It sounds like you're simply asking how to combine the two.  It's just

```
select ?p ?o where { 
  dbpedia:Barry_White ?p ?o .
  ?o a dbpedia-owl:MusicalWork
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=%20%20%20%20select%20?p%20?o%20where%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20dbpedia%3aBarry_White%20?p%20?o%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20?o%20a%20dbpedia-owl%3aMusicalWork%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on) (0 results)

That query doesn't actually have any results, because Barry White isn't related to anything that's a MusicalWork, evidently.  However, if you just ask for Works that he's associated with, you'll get a few results:

```
select ?p ?o where { 
  dbpedia:Barry_White ?p ?o .
  ?o a dbpedia-owl:Work
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=%20%20%20%20select%20?p%20?o%20where%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20dbpedia%3aBarry_White%20?p%20?o%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20?o%20a%20dbpedia-owl%3aWork%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on) (3 results)

Comment: Thank you @Joshua Taylor, your answer is the answer that i want. I start to view the SPARQL Documentation an Tutorial, but i have some problems with the syntax, but i want to learn to fix it. Thank you so much.